# Миграция базы данных Moodle с одного сервера на другой

Tags: база-данных, резервное-копирование, миграция, moodle

Здравствуйте. 
Стоит задача перенести все пользовательские данные (курсы, пользователей, группы) с одного сервера с Moodle на другой сервер (главное - курсы!). На обоих используется Windows с портативной версией Moodle (идет в комплекте XAMPP). Вопрос - как это сделать? База данных представляет собой просто список файлов. [Официальная документация](https://docs.moodle.org/33/en/Moodle_migration) ясности не вносит (способ переноса указан для Linux). Там же написано, что для переноса можно использовать PhpMyAdmin, но на портативной версии Moodle с XAMPP PhpMyAdmin не работает:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Прошу подсказать способ импортировать эту базу данных с одного сервера на другой.

Comment: А что мешает просто скопировать файлы? а там укажите к ним путь, подключитесь и всё

Comment: Пользовательские данные лежат в двух директориях - moodledata и папка с базой данных. В отношении первой директории этот способ применим, но с базами данных не все так легко. Это просто не работает, я пробовал.

Comment: Портативная версия для этого не совсем подходит (т.к. она не предназначена для сетевого "боевого" использования). Нужно было устанавливать на Windows полноценную версию. Если главное - это курсы, то их можно просто экспортировать, а затем импортировать в Moodle, установленный на другом сервере.